# Compiler gives "excess element in array initializer" warning in objective C with 2D C-array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array, compiler-warnings

I'm just learning Objective C and writing a program to aid people in learning to play the guitar. I wanted to create a 2D array containing (almost) all the notes on a guitar neck. Since there are six strings on the guitar and twelve notes in an octave, I created a 6 x 12 array. **EDIT: solution is now at bottom**

*The intention here is for the array to be read as* **(string),(fret number)**.

```
int strings[6][12] = {
    { {0, 8},{0, 9},{0, 10},{0, 11} ,{0, 12} ,{0, 1}, {0, 2},{0, 3},{0, 4},{0, 5},{0, 6},{0, 7} },
    { {1, 3},{1, 4},{1, 5},{1, 6},{1, 7},{1, 8,},{1, 9},{1, 10},{1, 11} ,{1, 12},{1, 1},{1, 2} },
    { {2, 12},{2, 1},{2, 2},{2, 3},{2, 4},{2, 5},{2, 6},{2, 7},{2, 8},{2, 9},{2, 10},{2, 11} },
    { {3, 6}, {3, 7} , {3, 8} , {3, 9} ,{3, 10} ,{3, 11} ,{3, 12} ,{3, 1} ,{3, 2} ,{3, 3} ,{3, 4} ,{3, 5} },
    { {4, 1} ,{4, 2} ,{4, 3} ,{4, 4} ,{4, 5} ,{4, 6} ,{4, 7} ,{4, 8} ,{4, 9} , {4, 10} ,{4, 11} ,{4, 12} },
    { {5, 9},{5, 10},{5, 11} , {5, 12} ,{5, 1},{5, 2},{5, 3},{5, 4},{5, 5},{5, 6},{5, 7},{5, 8} }
};
```

The problem is, XCode throws an warning: "excess elements in array initializer." What am I doing wrong? I've counted the elements numerous times and still am left scratching my head.

Comment: What you really want, it seems, is an array of 6 arrays of 12 arrays of 2 integers.

Comment: To give a bit more detail from @JoachimPileborg 's correct answer-  use int strings[6][12][2] = ...

Comment: Often when I see N-dimensional arrays, I think "missing objects".  Maybe what you really want is an array of NSObject subclasses called Strings, and maybe those have arrays of custom objects called Frets, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Moved from the question to an actual answer post:

> Thanks to you cool people, I figured out the problem. In the event
>   someone else has this problem, here is my solution. I came to realize
>   that the problem was that I had two integers assigned in each array
>   slot, effectively making the array a 3D array. Since the first number
>   in each pair is just the string number, I went ahead and just got rid
>   of it. No more warnings!**
>
> ```
> int strings[6][12] =    {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, // High e
>                         3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, // B
>                         12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, //G
>                         6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, // D
>                         1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, // A
>                         8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }; // E
> ```